# Style attribute is not working with AngualrJS bindings at design Time

Tags: html, css, angularjs, visual-studio-2013

```
 <div class="progress" style="width: {{Event.Methods.GetProgress()}}%"></div>
```

If I use above angularJS binding with the style attribute it shows below mentioned errors on it.But run time it works perfectely.How can I remove those design time issues on VS 2013 Ultimate.

[image]

[image]

**EDIT**

```
 ng-style="{width: {{Event.Methods.GetProgress()}}%}"
```

it shows as 15% but not adjust the 'width' of the progress bar. :(

[image]

Comment: did you tried {{Event.Methods.GetProgress()}} write this in somewhere else and see if it works or not

Comment: @NarekMamikonyan It's working.But the problem is with the style attribute on design time.But run time it's giving expected result though.

Comment: please try with ng-style="{width: Event.Methods.GetProgress()}"

Comment: @NarekMamikonyan Nope.It's not working.Width is not changing.it shows as 15% but not adjust the width of the progress bar.I have used it as ng-style="{width: {{Event.Methods.GetProgress()}}%}" :(

Comment: its not right ng-style="{width: Event.Methods.GetProgress() + '%'}"

Comment: @NarekMamikonyan Yes. You're right.Can you put this as the answer,then I can accept it.Thanks a lot. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
ng-style="{width: Event.Methods.GetProgress() + '%'}"
```